# use python replace json data key by keyword

Tags: python, json, filter, replace

how to convert old json from  logic_1、logic_2 all keyname rename to logic (remove underline and series number)  (ps: data from json file multi data via loop get)

```
[
    {
        "logic_1": "NOT",   
        "StudyDescription": "",
        "SeriesDescription": "C\\+",
        "ImageComments": ""
    },
    {
        "logic_2": "NOT",
        "StudyDescription": "\\-C",
        "SeriesDescription": "\\-C",
        "ImageComments": "\\-C"
    }
]
```

to

```
[
        {
            "logic": "NOT",   
            "StudyDescription": "",
            "SeriesDescription": "C\\+",
            "ImageComments": ""
        },
        {
            "logic": "NOT",
            "StudyDescription": "\\-C",
            "SeriesDescription": "\\-C",
            "ImageComments": "\\-C"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look for the key to replace like this

```
import re

arr = [
    {
        "logic_1": "NOT",
        "StudyDescription": "",
        "SeriesDescription": "C\\+", "ImageComments": ""},
    {
        "logic_2": "NOT",
        "StudyDescription": "\\-C",
        "SeriesDescription": "\\-C",
        "ImageComments": "\\-C",
    },
]

for data in arr:
    toswap = []
    for key in data.keys():
        match = re.search("_\d+$", key) # looking for _ followed by number
        if match is not None:
            new_key = key[0 : match.start()]
            toswap.append((key, new_key,))
    for key in toswap:
        data[key[1]] = data[key[0]]
        del data[key[0]]

print(arr)
```

Comment: thank you so much !! the code help me make it work!!  you awesome guy

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use regular expression to match key
2.then add a new key value into dict.
3.then delete the old key value pair.

```
obj = re.compile('logic_\d*')
for dic in arr:
    match = obj.search(str(dic.keys())) # matching key
    if len(match.group) != 0:
       dic['logic'] = dic[match.group()] # adding a key value 
       del dic[match.group()] # deleting the old key value
```